# How to load a user in React-Redux app only when logged in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, redux, redux-toolkit

The project in question is an e-commerce web app.
It allows a user to add items to cart, and after register/login to proceede to payment.
The problem is, when the homepage loads, if the user is not logged in, the errors appear in devtools:

> GET http://.../profile 401 (Unauthorized)
> GET http://.../stripeapikey 401 (Unauthorized)

Here is a piece of code that controls this behavior:

actions/user.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const loadUser = () => async dispatch => {

    try {
        dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_USER_REQ' })

        const { data } = await axios.get('/api/profile')

        dispatch({
            type: 'LOAD_USER_SUCCESS',
            payload: data.user
        })

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: 'LOAD_USER_FAIL',
            payload: error.response.data.message
        })
    }
}

export const clearErrors = () => async dispatch => {

    dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR_ERRORS' })
}
```

reducers/user.js:

```
export const authReducer = (state = { user: {} }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case 'LOAD_USER_REQ':
            return {
                loading: true,
                isAuthenticated: false
            }

        case 'LOAD_USER_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                user: action.payload
            }

        case 'LOAD_USER_FAIL':
            return {
                loading: false,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                user: null,
                error: action.payload
            }

        case 'CLEAR_ERRORS':
            return {
                ...state,
                error: null
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

store.js:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import { authReducer } from './reducers/user'

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        auth: authReducer
    }
})

export default store
```

components/Header.js:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const Header = () => {

    const { loading, user } = useSelector(state => state.auth)

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <nav className="navbar bg-primary">
                <div>
                    {user ?
                        <div>{/* Profile, Logout btn etc. */}</div> :
                        !loading && <Link to="/#" className="btn">Log in</Link>
                    }
                </div>
            </nav>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default Header
```

The rest of the components (Home, Payment, Profile), are generic rafc like so:

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js'
import axios from 'axios'

import Header from './components/Header'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Payment from './components/Payment'
import Profile from './components/Profile'

import { loadUser } from './actions/user'
import store from './store'

export default function App() {

  const [stripeApiKey, setStripeApiKey] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {

    store.dispatch(loadUser());

    (async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get('/api/stripeapikey')
      setStripeApiKey(data.stripeApiKey)
    })().catch(console.error)

  }, [])

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          {/* These 2 routes are protected */}
          <Route path="profile" element={<Profile />} />
          {stripeApiKey &&
            <Route path="payment"
              element={<Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeApiKey)}><Payment /></Elements>}
            />
          }
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import App from './App'
import store from './store'

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
)
```

In package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.0.1",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^2.4.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^2.2.2",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
"proxy": "https://happyfruits.onrender.com"
```

Is there a way to tell the app to try loading the user and his stripe api key only when he is logged in?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an early return in loadUser.

```
export const loadUser = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (!getState().auth.authenticated) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        dispatch({ type: LOAD_USER_REQ })

        const { data } = await axios.get('/profile')

        dispatch({
            type: LOAD_USER_SUCCESS,
            payload: data.user
        })

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: LOAD_USER_FAIL,
            payload: error.response.data.message
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried it, but then instead of a login button I get a logout button, as if user is logged in, but it's not.

Comment: @5-fingeredSloth My hunch would be that is because you check for `state.user` to determine whether or not to check the login or login button. And because you set the initial state of `user` to {}, that evaluates to true. Try this is your reducer:

`export const authReducer = (state = { user: null }, action) => {...}`

Comment: The error is gone, but now when I reload logged-in user, it gets logged-out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is that `App` dispatches the action to load a user at the same time it initiates a fetch to the Stripe APIs.

Update the `loadUser` action to be a Redux-Toolkit (RTK) action so you can wait for it to complete and then conditionally call the Stripe API. In fact, I recommend you convert all the auth code to use RTK. Using RTK also cuts out a ton of boilerplate code.

Example:

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

export const loadUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/loadUser",
  async (_, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get('/api/profile');
      return data.user;
    } catch(error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error.response.data.message);
    }
  }
);

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    error: null,
    loading: false,
    user: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    clearErrors: (state, action) => {
      state.error = null;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(loadUser.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(loadUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = action.payload;
        state.loading = false;
      })
      .addCase(loadUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.user = null;
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
        state.loading = false;
      });
  },
});

export const { clearErrors } = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authReducer from './slices/authSlice';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer
  }
});

export default store;
```

Use a mounting `useEffect` hook to dispatch the initial `loadUser` action and unwrap the returned Promise result, e.g. if it resolved or rejected, then continue to chain the fetching of the stripe key and state update.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import Header from './components/Header'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Payment from './components/Payment'
import Profile from './components/Profile'

import { loadUser } from './actions/user'
import store from './store'

export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [stripeApiKey, setStripeApiKey] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadUser())
      .unwrap()
      .then(() => axios.get('/api/stripeapikey'))
      .then(({ data }) => setStripeApiKey(data.stripeApiKey))
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          {/* These 2 routes are protected */}
          <Route path="profile" element={<Profile />} />
          {stripeApiKey &&
            <Route path="payment"
              element={<Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeApiKey)}><Payment /></Elements>}
            />
          }
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

If loading a user ***always*** involves also fetching an associated Stripe key then go ahead and include that in the `loadUser` action and `auth` state.

Example:

```js
export const loadUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/loadUser",
  async (_, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const { data: userData } = await axios.get('/api/profile');
      
      if (!userData.user) {
        return thunkApi.rejectWithValue("no user data");
      }

      const { data: stripeData } = await axios.get('/api/stripeapikey');

      return {
        user: userData.user
        stripeApiKey: stripeData.stripeApiKey
      };
    } catch(error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error.response?.data?.message ?? error);
    }
  }
);

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    error: null,
    loading: false,
    stripeApiKey: '',
    user: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    clearErrors: (state, action) => {
      state.error = null;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(loadUser.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(loadUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = action.payload.user;
        state.stripeApiKey = action.payload.stripeApiKey;
        state.loading = false;
      })
      .addCase(loadUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.user = null;
        state.stripeApiKey = '';
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
        state.loading = false;
      });
  },
});
```

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Header from './components/Header'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Payment from './components/Payment'
import Profile from './components/Profile'

import { loadUser } from './actions/user'
import store from './store'

export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const stripeApiKey = useSelector(state => state.auth.stripeApiKey);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          {/* These 2 routes are protected */}
          <Route path="profile" element={<Profile />} />
          {stripeApiKey &&
            <Route path="payment"
              element={<Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeApiKey)}><Payment /></Elements>}
            />
          }
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the express answer. Gonna try this asap (it's past midnight here :)). Will be back with feedback.

Comment: @5-fingeredSloth Welcome. If it's not already spot-on it should likely get you close to what I understand you wanting. Let me know.

Comment: Hello.
About this: "It looks like the issue is that App dispatches the action to load a user at the same time it initiates a fetch to the Stripe APIs." - the problem (GET http://.../profile 401 (Unauthorized)) was present before any of the Stripe functions were added to the code (App.js and elsewhere). So, I'll take your advice, and try to fix that first.

Comment: @5-fingeredSloth I see. So is this `loadUser` and `"/profile"` API endpoint *not* the authentication endpoint? I guess a user is going somewhere else in the app and logging in, which uses a different API and different state, but hitting the `"/profile"` endpoint before the user authenticates returns a 401? Looks like both it and the `http://.../stripeapikey` endpoint are returning 401s. Sorry that I only had the information you had provided regarding the issue of calling the Stripe API *after* (presumably) the `loadUser` action completed.

Comment: @5-fingeredSloth So are you only wanting to dispatch `loadUser` and fetch the stripe API key if there's an authenticated user? Can you share how that is set/determined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256573/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-5-fingeredsloth).